# Sftp Retry Logic Inside Azure function App

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, sftp, retry-logic

I am facing one issue ,where i am getting intermittent error message

> "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

while trying to connect sftp server. I am trying to connect sftp inside azure function app. I believe this error happens while there is a connection issue.

To handle that I need to implement a retry logic incase if such error happens repeatedly connect sftp server with a specified delay until configured maximum retry count is reached. I believe the maximum execution  time allowed for function app is 5 minutes (*need to hear it from azure expert*).

Can anyone help how i can achieve this retry functionality in C#?

I am using `Renci.SshNet` nuget package for managing sftp

```
using (var _sftpCn = new SftpClient(host, port, userName, password))
{
    _sftpCn.Connect();//error happens on this line:"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"
    log.LogInformation("Successful");
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(datacontent);
    sftpCl.WriteAllBytes("{remotePath}", byteArray);
    log.LogInformation("Sent successfully");
    _sftpCn.Disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) here.

> Polly is a .NET resilience and transient-fault-handling library that
> allows developers to express policies such as Retry, Circuit Breaker,
> Timeout, Bulkhead Isolation, and Fallback in a fluent and thread-safe
> manner.

It is free library can be downloaded as [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/polly/) from this command:

`dotnet add package Polly`

There are many more things to it, please see [here](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-http-call-retries-exponential-backoff-polly) for more details and examples.

Comment: retry to be applicbe only if it throws ""An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"..is it achievable through this?

Comment: Yes @vmb. You can specify the exceptions/faults you want the policy to handle.

Comment: Is it work inside azure function?